# MongoDB Aggregation Framework Group Performance

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework

Working with the MongoDB aggregation framework it is clear that the `$group` function is the bottleneck.   By using `explain()` on some find queries, I'm able to tailor my indexes to reduce table scans significantly, however it seems that `$group` does not take into account any `$sort` that happens before, even if I end up sorting by the fields it will end up doing the `$group` by.

Besides simply reducing the result set, are there any practical ways to improve the performance of the `$group` function?  I'm almost tempted to take advantage of the sort, and just do the `$group` in my own application, but there must be an elegant and performant solution using the framework.

I'm noticing that as the result set from the `$match` increases, the `$group` time also increases.

My document is basically like this

```
{
 a: (String)
 b: (String)
}
```

with a `pipeline` that looks something like

```
$match :{ a : 'frank'}
$sort : { b : 1 }
$group : { _id : { $b : b }}
```

It is surprising to me, because I assume by the time it gets to the group, the data is loaded into memory, and since the fields are indexed, a few thousand records shouldn't take that much time to load into memory. Is this not the case?

Just seems that the `$sort` has no effect on the overall performance.  Is there a way to use indexes, as well as the previous functions of the pipeline to improve the performance of the `$group`?  Also, does `$group` stay within the result set from the previous functions, or does it go back to an entire table scan (I'm pretty sure, or hopefully that's not it)

Comment: You have to use a sorted group with $first or $last for $sort to make any sense in a $group, also $group does not use indexes, also $group should work only on the docs from the last pipeline

Comment: Do you have a compound index on {a:1, b:1}?   Also, what is your actual $group - the syntax you have in incorrect, can you provide your actual complete $group step?

Comment: 1. Compound index: not yet. Will add with care, and probably in the background as to not bring operations on this collection to a grinding halt.

2. So the pipeline is:
`$match` `$sort` `$project` `$group`
The $match is an $in function (to pass multiple a's). 
The $group is as follows:

` { $group: { _id: { b: "$b"}, sum: { $sum: "$hits" }, rows: { $sum: 1 }, count_x: { $sum: "$x_count" }, count_y: { $sum: "$y_count" } } }`   where `$x_count` and `$y_count` are from the projection phase.

Comment: without the compound index the sort has to be done in memory - that's expensive *especially* when you don't have a $limit...  why sort if you aren't going to limit?

Comment: are you on 2.2 or 2.4 version of MongoDB?

Comment: What I'm interested in, are those who have the highest `rows * hits` (hence `$sum:1` above per group) So I'd be able to do a limit, if I knew the rowcount per group, but I need to do a group first, in order to have that.  Ideally I'd be able to limit by rowcount where b=$b, but grouping has to happen for that to be available.     On 2.2 moving to 2.4.  What does 2.4 bring in this case?     And yes, the sort above only makes sense when the compound index will exist.  

If I sort by the field I'm grouping on, does MongoDB take advantage of having that ordering done before the `$group`?